# Programmatically determine latest Gradle version?

Tags: api, gradle, versioning

Is there a way to find, via an API or CLI, the latest available version of Gradle?

I'm working on a tool to check versions of dependencies and compare them to the latest versions, and I need a way to determine what the latest version of Gradle that is available.

**To be clear, I am not looking for the version of Gradle I already have.** I know how to get that any number of ways. I'm just looking for some officially maintained endpoint I can call to determine the latest version available.

Comment: You can use some links from the official Gradle Github repository (e.g.: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/latest )  : using simple regex you can extract the latest version from the returned string.

Comment: I considered something like that, and may go with it if it is truly the only option, but extracting a value from the HTML page is definitely less than ideal.

Comment: Is your tool implemented as a Gradle plugin/script? if so , you could use Gradle configuration/dependencies feature to get latest version of the Gradle core module ( e.g.: `gradleLatest ("org.gradle:gradle-core:latest.release")` ) and get the resolved artefact version programatically. you can then use the resolved version to perform your check, in a dedicated task for example. I

Comment: The tool itself is written in Node. That is another solution I could use, since I could run it from the command-line, but that seems a bit heavy-duty as well.

Answer (score 3):

Gradle has an API to retrieve all sorts of information:
https://services.gradle.org/

For the current version:
`GET` https://services.gradle.org/versions/current

```json
{
  "version" : "6.8.1",
  "buildTime" : "20210122132008+0000",
  "current" : true,
  "snapshot" : false,
  "nightly" : false,
  "releaseNightly" : false,
  "activeRc" : false,
  "rcFor" : "",
  "milestoneFor" : "",
  "broken" : false,
  "downloadUrl" : "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-bin.zip",
  "checksumUrl" : "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-bin.zip.sha256",
  "wrapperChecksumUrl" : "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-wrapper.jar.sha256"
}
```

You can get the data using `curl` and then use `jq` to extract the `version` key.
Node.js has in-built JSON support so this will be even easier.

```sh
CURRENT_GRADLE_VERSION="$(curl -s https://services.gradle.org/versions/current | jq -r '.version')"

echo "${CURRENT_GRADLE_VERSION}" # prints 6.8.1
```